# Is it possible to use android smartphone as vga monitor for my pc?

Tags: usb, android, external-display

I cant find anything on this topic.
I have PC without monitor (home server) and occasionally I would like to be able to connect monitor and see what is going on there (during boot), but I dont have any monitor.
I was wandering if it is possible by any way, with some smart converter etc, use android smartphone as a screen/monitor for my server?

Comment: @Hennes, Why would you edit out the "VGA" tag? The question is specifically about how to convert the .VGA hardware output into a form suitable for smartphone.

Comment: Because I doubted that he was looking for 640x480 in 16 colours.

Comment: During boot is nearly impossible, you'd basically need a third computer-like device with an A/D converter as framegrabber if your PC really has only VGA, and those things are rare enough to be expensive. A second-hand monitor is a lot cheaper. After boot, you can use a remote desktop protocol like VNC.